# Are there any blue Sith?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, sith

In honor of [Dr. Seuss' birthday](https://www.google.com/search?q=dr%20seuss&oq=dr%20seuss&aqs=chrome..69i57.2379j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8&safe=active&ssui=on#safe=active&q=dr%20seuss%27s%20birthday%20), I wanted to make a Star Wars version of the famous phrase:

> One fish
>   Two fish
>   Red fish
>   Blue fish

[image]

"Sith" kind of sounds like "fish", so I've got

> One Sith (Vader)
>   Two Sith (Sidious and Vader)
>   Red Sith (Darth Maul)
>   Blue Sith (?)

A "Red Sith" would probably be Darth Maul, but I can't think of a "Blue Sith". Canon is prefered but Legends is OK too.

Comment: The legends race called the Bith were blue in color, and aligned with the empire. In SWTOR legends some were sith.

Comment: Here's what I went with to create my tribute (I hope this link works): http://www.queeky.com/attachements/one-sith-two-sith-red-sith-blue-sith

Comment: Nice! There isn't really a well known blue sith. There are some in the legends though. Also I meant to say *Chiss* not Bith. http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Chiss/Legends

Comment: [So this exists](http://img12.deviantart.net/4697/i/2014/287/a/a/one_sith__two_sith__red_sith__blue_sith_by_jamesramos-d82tyoe.jpg) [and this](https://bobbiblogger.files.wordpress.com/2012/03/sith.jpg)

Comment: For One Sith you could use another one, e.g. Plagueis, Tyrannus etc.

Comment: +1 for the most absurd Star Wars-related idea I've ever heard of. Keep up the good work, mate!

Comment: Legends villain superstar Grand Admiral Thrawn was blue. But not a Sith. :-(

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can always go with Sidious' hologram. It's canon.

[image: Darth Sidious hologram]

You could also use Maul's hologram. That would be even funnier since the red and blue Sith would be the same person.

[image: Darth Maul hologram]

Comment: If you're including pictures, the hologram of Darth Maul would work well right after the picture of regular Darth Maul.

Answer (score 40):

In Legends, [Darth Ruin](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Ruin) is blue.

[image]
<sup>Picture from *Book of Sith: Secrets from the Dark Side*</sup>

[image]
<sup>Picture from *Jedi vs. Sith: The Essential Guide to the Force*</sup>

And of course, Anakin *was* a Sith, and when he became a Force-ghost, he was blue.

[image]

Comment: Sadly that image of Anakin is legends :/

Comment: @Oak I put that in the same category of canon as I put "Han shot second".  Which is to say, I don't :)

Answer (score 4):

[Sev'rance Tann](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sev'rance_Tann) and [Kung'urama'nuruodo](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Nuru_Kungurama) are Chiss force-users. Chiss' appearance is basically human, but with blue skin.

The former was a "Dark Acolyte" under Count Dooku. I believe she's only found in the 2012 RTS Galactic Battlegrounds.

The latter was trained as a Jedi, and appeared in the Secret Missions Comics, and a Clone Wars comic released for Free Comic Book day in 2011. So I believe both "Legends" (but post-Lucas recent ones).

Answer (score 2):

I already made this a few years ago. 
Blue Sith is Asajj Ventress, Dooku's Apprentice. 

[One Sith, Two Sith, Red Sith, Blue Sith](http://jamesramos.deviantart.com/art/One-Sith-Two-Sith-Red-Sith-Blue-Sith-488486606) by jamesramos on [DeviantArt](http://www.deviantart.com)

Comment: [One Sith, Two Sith, Red Sith, Blue Sith by James Ramos] <img> http://img12.deviantart.net/4697/i/2014/287/a/a/one_sith__two_sith__red_sith__blue_sith_by_jamesramos-d82tyoe.jpg <img>

Comment: Ventress is more white than blue and she isn't a true Sith.

Comment: Well, she's the best KNOWN option. The only reason she wasn't "True Sith" is simply because of the rule of two. Had Sidious died she'd be True. Also, if you want to go there, Maul isn't Sith either, and/or neither is Dooku since Maul survived and they both were alive at the same time. Anyway, I'm a big fan and made this for fun. sorry if you don't enjoy it.