# Are there any blonde Jedi?

Tags: star-wars

Luke Skywalker seems to have brown not blonde hair in my opinion.

Are there any truly blonde Jedi (preferably, named characters)? If not why?

*I would prefer if it was official canon.*

To downvoters this is no more vague there [Are there any blue Sith?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/121043/51379).

Comment: @Adamant I guess yeah luke looks brown to me http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2011/04/01/article-1372171-0B6D6D3000000578-157_224x360.jpg

Comment: Because Blonde Jedis keep loosing their lightsaber? Nyah, can't be it. Anakin kept losing his lightsaber too.

Comment: Do [younglings (far left)](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/2a/f6/a2/2af6a2b267a01711f85dfd7808182d73.jpg) count?

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh I would prefer if he/she has name.

Comment: While I suspect I can see why, it is still good to provide the OP with feedback after DV'ing with the reason for the DV or how the question can be improved.

Comment: @William Of course they have a name and backstory! They're a cursory character in a Star Wars movie!

Comment: To those voting to close, I would say that this is no more broad than [Are there any blue Sith?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/121043/51379). In *Star Wars*, after all, there are probably more blue people than blond people.

Comment: I’ll vote to reopen, consistent with what I said earlier. But as for downvotes, there’s not much you can do. People may be downvoting because it’s not a very difficult question.

Comment: @Adamant  I just don't like taking a negative hit in rep when one question is upvoted like crazy and the other is not so much(when they are quite similar).  Reopening it won't change the rep.  I'm not sure if the blue sith question is good either.  I'm not going to attempt to delete because I'm pretty sure I can't.  Thanks for the upvote!  I understand if they don't want similar red head questions though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Oppo Rancisis

Though not human, [Rancisis](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Oppo_Rancisis) was unmistakeably blond:

He appeared in *The Phantom Menace*, *Attack of the Clones*, and various other media.

[image]

It’s perhaps worth noting that Luke is canonically called “blond”:

> A younger human, a blond teenager, was hauled up from the floor
> looking dazed, then disappeared into one of the cantina’s dark
> pockets.
>
> <sub>*The Princess, The Scoundrel, and the Farm Boy*</sub>

Comment: Looks bleached brunette to me :)

Comment: @DVK-in-exile - Definitely strawberry blond. ;)

Comment: People close to me officially refer to me as "color-stupid". I'm the least authoritative person on the planet when it comes to identifying and distinguishing colors.

Comment: Also, please make the image smaller. you can add "m" or "s" to filename before `.jpg`

Answer (score 10):

Yes, at least in Legends canon. [Cray Mingla](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Cray_Mingla) of The New Jedi Order is officially described as "blonde".

> "Luke's student Cray"? Han came over to her side. "**The blonde with the legs**?"
>   Leia elbowed him hard in the ribs. "'The blonde with the legs' happens to be the most brilliant innovator in artificial intelligence to come along in the past decade"
>   (*Barbara Hambly, "Children of the Jedi"*)

Also, Luke is blonde officially as per toys :)

> [Vintage Star Wars Loose Luke Skywalker](http://www.brianstoys.com/vintage-loose-afa-graded-sw-luke-skywalker-blond-hair-dark-glossy-pants-afa-11748562.html#.WFlron2iDN4) (Blonde Hair/Dark Glossy Pants) Action Figure (Made in Taiwan) AFA 80 NM #11748562 ...

Comment: Legends isn’t really official canon, though, even with the word “officially.”

Comment: @Adamant - it is to me. I shall never bow down to oppressive tyranny of Darth Mickey.